# Comparing BST node with str issue

Tags: python, string, binary-search-tree, nodes, typeerror

This is the search function I'm using to try and find a specific value held in a BST that holds words. However when I run it I am given an error on the line `elif root < root.value:`

```
def search(root, target):
    print("Target is: " + target + "\n")
    if root.value == target or root == None:
        print("Found target: " + target)
        return root
    elif root < root.value:
        return search(root.left, target)
        print("Searching left")
    else:
        return search(root.right, target)
        print("Searching right")
```

It says `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Node' and 'str'`, now as far as I know I can use `<` and `>` too compare regular strings, but I cant seem to use it to compare a root a node containing a string and another node containing a string? Is their another way I should go about comparing?

Comment: Define comparison for your nodes (with `def __lt__()`), or extract string from node and compare those.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare `root` to `root.value`.

I think you meant something like this:

```
def search(root, target):
    print("Target is: " + target + "\n")
    if root.value == target or root is None: # changed to is, 
                                             # though you may want a 4th case for this
        print("Found target: " + target)
        return root
    elif target < root.value: #Notice I changed this to target instead of root
        print("Searching left")
        return search(root.left, target)
    else:
        print("Searching right")
        return search(root.right, target)
```